# Running a lua script as a gel script

Tags: lua

I have the following lua script that separates a string in its proper words:

```
names = "aa bb cc dd"
words = {}
for word in names:gmatch("%w+") do table.insert(words, word) end
for k,v in pairs(words) do print(k,v) end
```

I am using a program called Graphite, which is a platform for computer graphics and more. In its readme it is written:

> You can write a LUA script and run it with Graphite. Just load the
>   script using GEL -> execute file.

Having very small experience with LUA and zero knowledge about what GEL is, I am having trouble running a script. After some googling I found this: http://gema.sourceforge.net/new/gel.shtml#3_1 ,
but it is still not so clear to me what the connection between gel and lua is. In this website it is described as: a Lua binding for Gema, a general purpose text processing utility.

The above script for example works as intended in the lua interpreter. On the other hand, when I try to execute it as a .gel script (because the software mentioned above requires a .gel script) it returns a syntax error.

Any idea on how to make it run as a .gel script? Or any other comment that might help?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation more closely, you'll notice:

> - Embed the lua functions in the gema file using the new syntax `"![" "!]"`

They also have an example provided:

```
![
function inflog(x)
  if x>0 then return math.log(x)
  else return "-infty"
  end
end
!]

<N>=@lua{return inflog($0)}
```

Following the same example, the following should work:

```
![
function split(names)
    words = {}
    for word in names:gmatch("%w+") do table.insert(words, word) end
    for k, v in ipairs(words) do print(k, v) end
    return words
end
!]

<N>=@lua{return split($0)}
```

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. I copied  their website example in an empty file as is. When I try to run it I get:
 ![  
***^ 
***SyntaxError 
***: 
***invalid syntax. The ![ is not recognized

Comment: how are you running it?